# Tabulate categorical variable into dummies with proper labels

Tags: stata

I have a variable with proper labels:

```
        Sex |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
       Male |  9,043,349       48.70       48.70
     Female |  9,524,274       51.30      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total | 18,567,623      100.00
```

I'd like to create a table with summary statistics by categorical value. It doesn't make a lot of sense here as there is only two values, but let's do it anyways. I generate

```
 tab sex, gen(sexd_)
```

and then when I create the table:

```
. esttab test, replace cell("mean")  label

---------------------------------
                              (1)

                             mean
---------------------------------
sex==Male                .9028908
sex==Female              .0971092
---------------------------------
Observations               123943
---------------------------------
```

But the table shows the silly `sex==` prefix, I'd like to only have `Male` and `Female` here. This is because `tab, generate` creates the variables like that:

```
                              (1)

                             mean
---------------------------------
sex==Male                .9028908
sex==Female              .0971092
---------------------------------
Observations               123943
---------------------------------
```

How can I neatly create the labels I want, without manually going through all entries?

Answer (score 1):

The question could have helpfully given a minimal code example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for generic guidance. Here is one such with the results shown:

```
. clear

. set obs 2
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 2

. gen sex = _n - 1

. label def sex 0 Male 1 Female

. label val sex sex

. tab sex

        sex |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
       Male |          1       50.00       50.00
     Female |          1       50.00      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |          2      100.00

. tab sex, gen(sexd)

        sex |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
       Male |          1       50.00       50.00
     Female |          1       50.00      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |          2      100.00
```

`tabulate` doesn't offer an option to control variable labels for the new indicator variables (dummy variables in your terminology). So, it's a matter of how best to clean up.

The first principles approach is to loop over the variables and remove the offending prefixed text from the variable labels. Here we just select what follows the `==`. Another approach would to replace the text up to and including `==` with nothing, and so delete it.

```
foreach v of var sexd* { 
    local lbl : var label `v' 
    local lbl = substr(`"`lbl'"', strpos(`"`lbl'"', "==") + 2, .) 
    label var `v' `"`lbl'" 
}
```

There's a convenience command that does this in one. It must be installed as part of a package from SSC. The first command below need only be done once on any machine.

```
ssc inst labutil 
labvarch sexd*, after(==)
```

At worst, you have several such variables to fix. How could you efficiently identify which variable labels contain `==`? You could write a loop to do it, or use `findname` (`search findname` for latest download location).

```
findname, varlabeltext(*==*)
```

`findname` displays variable names for any variables matching; those names are accessible in `r(varlist)', so (given installation) this slashes its way through all possibly offending labels:

```
findname, varlabeltext(*==*) 
labvarch `r(varlist)', after(==)
```

Naturally you need to watch out for any false positives, that is, any variables where `==` is needed in the variable label.

You could always create the indicators by hand in the first place and create your own variable labels directly; or change the variable labels directly.